# Basic cloud9 project

Tags: html, cloud9-ide

I'm new to the cloud IDE setup and can't get my head around deployment and "workspaces". I tried making a basic site with html (to use javascript/css once I can figure out how to call the code into the html) as testing before running it on another website.

At the moment I'm using a basic text editor to tweak the html (for a custom Google Map), but cloud9 and the like highlight code in colour and complete functions etc. so it's easier to use (also I can't use an offline editor due to hardware).

I'm keen to learn more javascript but really only have basic web html/css skills so all the node.js files lose me a bit. Where can I find a really simple introduction to just writing, say, a html page and seeing it previewed? Or does it not work like that?

The tutorials I've found so far are going into scripting (e.g. "Cloud 9 IDE Basics" > http://vimeo.com/16273901)

Thanks, and sorry for asking such a beginner's question!

Answer (score 0):

Does the Cloud9 documentation site (https://docs.c9.io/) help?. It has articles ranging from the basics to more advanced topics, including some video tutorials.

Comment: I've looked through it and basically can't work out how to preview html - I can do it in jfiddle, or by putting it into an actual web page, but for some reason I can only get javascript to show as a preview. So even a simple <html><p>Hello world</p></html> wouldn't render, I'm not sure if it's not meant to be used for that though? I've tried both running and deploying and can't seem to figure out this pretty basic manoeuvre, kinda embarrassing...

Comment: I've just started looking at this site but top left on the menu bar has a Run icon. I've guessing by now you've resolved this?